# Push variable to array using name as key?

Tags: php

I have the following variables:

```
$something = 'whatever';
$hello = array();
$test = 123;
```

and I want to push them into an array like this:

```
$data['something'] = 'whatever';
$data['hello'] = array();
$data['test'] = 123;
```

I was wondering if there was some sort of PHP function (similar to `array_push()`) that can push a variable into an array, using the name of the variable as the key value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. [`compact()`](http://php.net/compact) will do exactly this.

Comment: yes, exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to append to an existing array or do you have to create a fresh array?

Comment: The function returns an array, but you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array-merge) to combine it with another array.

Comment: There is no way to use this with class member variables, like `$something->whatever`, right?

Comment: @Jakobud, wouldn't of thought so, it doesn't allow you to specify a context.